# keeping count and storing of text instances

Tags: vb.net, text, count, text-files, readline

I would like to make a simple code that counts the top three most recurring lines/ text in a txt file then saves that line/ text to another text file (this in turn will be read into AutoCAD’s variable system).

Forgetting the AutoCAD part which I can manage how do I in VB.net save the 3 most recurring lines of text each to its own text file see example below:

Text file to be read reads as follows:

APG
BTR
VTS
VTS
VTS
VTS
BTR
BTR
APG
PNG

The VB.net program would then save the text VTS to mostused.txt BTR to 2ndmostused.txt and APG to 3rdmostused.txt

How can this be best achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm C# developer, I'll use it:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
using(var sr = new StreamReader(file))
{
   var line = string.Empty;
   while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
   {
     var words = line.Split(' '); // get the words
     foreach(var word in words)
     {
       if(!dict.Contains(word)) dict.Add(word, 0);
       dict[word]++; // count them
     }
   }
}

var query = from d in dict select d order by d.Value; // now you have it sorted
int counter = 1;
foreach(var pair in query)
{
   using(var sw = new StreamWriter("file" + counter + ".txt"))
     sw.writer(pair.Key);
}
```

Comment: I think he does not want words in a line, just the lines, that makes it even more simple: add whole lines to dict